# Laravel Form Validation Reload F5

Tags: laravel

Estou com a seguinte dúvida:

Assim que faço o submit de um formulário ele faz a validação certinha, porém se dou F5 no navegador ele some com as mensagens de erro e some também os valores dos campos que já foram preenchidos.

Teria como eu corrigir isso?

Obrigado

Comment: Que tipo de formulario vc está submetendo e validando? Login? Cadastro de alguma coisa?

Comment: Olá Darlei, é um formulário simples de cadastro. Estou validando se os campos estão preenchidos e talz.

Comment: Existe uma função odl() no laravel, pode conferir se ela te ajuda, mas normalmente se der um f5 em um formulario ele vai ficar vazio mesmo, o que poderia fazer tambem é validar os campos por JS, AJAX ou algo que não redirecione a pagina, mas caso tenha que usar funções do controller, pode usar o old(), ele mantem o value nos inputs depois de dar o submit.

Comment: Então Darlei eu estou usando o old para recuperar os dados preenchidos do formulário, meu único problema é que quando dou o F5 no navegador some até esses dados e as mensagens de validação.

Comment: Porque apertar F5, as mensagens de erro e retorno de valores é um flash só funciona uma vez ( se eu não estiver enganado e se não mudou isso)

Comment: Então Virgilio pensei que tinha um parâmetro que inibisse isso. Sabe se teria alguma maneira de reverter isso?